# How can I properly validate for a unique email address?

Tags: php, ajax

I was trying to have my form validate an email address onblur or onkeyup, to check to see if the email address already exists in my database.

Not sure if I'm almost there with this code, something isn't working though. Right now, as soon as I start typing in the field, the input box for email is flagged based on how I would want it flagged if an email address was entered if it was already in my database. The else statement in AJAX doesn't work, and if I submit the form anyway, I get a message on the page from an error box I created mentioning a syntax error.

Also, part of my php is using mysqli and mysql, does that make a difference with trying to get this input field to validate?

The input id is email and the name is Email; I think I have that correct in my code, not entirely sure though.

PHP:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'host');

$first = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['First']));
$last = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Last']));
$city = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['City']));
$state = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['State']));
$country = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Country']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$tempt = $_POST['tempt'];
$tempt2 = $_POST['tempt2'];


$link = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','members') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE email =?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['Email']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
/* bind result variables */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
/* fetch value */
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

if ($count == 0) {
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}


if ($tempt == 'http://' && empty($tempt2)) {

    $error_message = '';
    $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9­-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/";

    if(!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

        $error_message .= "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";
    }
    if (empty($first)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your first name.</p>";
    }
    if (empty($last)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your last name.</p>";
    }
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    if (valid != '') {
    $('form #response2').removeClass().addClass('error2')
        .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
}

    var valid = '';

    $('#email').keyup(function() {
        $.post('script.php', { 'Email' : $(this).val() }, function(data) {
             if(data !== 'true') {
                $('#email').css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
                $('#email').css('background-color','#ffcece');
                valid += '<p>This email has already subscribed.</p>';
             }else{
                $('#email').css('background-color','green');
             }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your database connection on your php page?

Comment: It is toward the bottom of my page

Comment: But you are querying with that to return an email match correct? Can you post that?

Comment: I just have it defined.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you need to do a query then, see @amit_183.

Comment: You need to actually do a query to the database to do the check. then if you get a hit in your database, you return the true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fetch all the emails to check whether the posted email already exist.
U can do a simple count and test the amount of records. If its 0 then the email is not in the database

Something like this should work (not tested) :

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="txt_email" id="txt_email" />
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('#txt_email').blur(function() {
        $.post('location/to/script.php', { 'txt_email' : $(this).val() }, function(data) {
             if(data !== 'true') {
                $('#txt_email').css('background', 'red');
             }else{
                $('#txt_email').css('background', 'white');
             }
        });
    });
});
```

script.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT count(*) FROM user WHERE email =?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['txt_email']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
/* bind result variables */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
/* fetch value */
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

if ($count == 0) {
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: What is the reference to mybd?

Comment: In your case it would be : mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

Comment: Any email I type into the email field now, is flagged in a style that would suggest that it is not valid. And when I submit the form anyway, there is a syntax error that flashes on the page.

Comment: I've changed the script. I had an error in the php script. Other than thats this little snippet seems to work. See http://www.darkbee.be/web/test.php with any email and test with `test@example.com`to flag.
U still need to test the email again in your PHP backend obvious :)

Comment: This line mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['txt_email']);   should txt_email be my email id, or name?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#txt_email').blur(function() {
        $.post('location/to/script.php', { 'txt_email' : $(this).val() }, function(data) {
             if(data !== 'true') {
                $('#txt_email').css('background', 'red');
             }else{
                $('#txt_email').css('background', 'white');
             }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!